# SIP address for group chat in Skype for business

Tags: windows-10, skype, chat, skype-for-business, uri

i searched a lot for the URI syntax of SIP address for group chat in Skype for business,

i found answer only for a individual chat

so i want to is there any syntax for group chat or chat with multiple peoples

also, i tried adding a Distribution list ID, which does't helped,

Please help me with the proper URI syntax to chat with multiple people

Answer (score 1):

Accepts multiple SIP URIs specified inside angle brackets (<>) without any separator.

```
im:<sip:user1@host><sip:user2@host>
```

[Refer MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lyncserver/lync-server-2013-starting-lync-from-another-application)

Comment: Does not seem to work with Skype office 2016